# Tailwind CSS IntelliSense does not provide suggestions in a ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I created a ReactJS project using `create-react-project` command. I npm installed **tailwindcss** and created a **tailwind.config.js** file.

Now to make my life easier I also installed an extension called Tailwind CSS IntelliSense and reloaded VSCode. The extension still does not give suggestions in my JavaScript files.

At first, i thought it is maybe because it works only with html extensions or that the reactjs files uses `className` for adding CSS classes as class keyword is reserved. So, I tried to edit **index.html** file but not suggestions in HTML files as well.

Please tell what else can I tryout?

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 40):

Edit your `settings.json` as below:

```json
{
  // other settings
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "html": "HTML"
  },
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

**Here's how to get Tailwind Intellisense to work with React files**

1. Go to Tailwind CSS settings and add Javascript support `"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": { "plaintext": "javascript" }`
2. Reload vscode

If this doesn't fix things, try using `ctrl + space` before adding a class name.

[View image of Tailwind settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rn9G.png)

Comment: `cmd + shift + p` to open JSON settings in VSCode. You can then add the suggested code there

Comment: It only works when I press `ctrl + space` but now I'm wondering why It doesn't work normally

Answer (score 14):

I faced this issue even after configuring `tailwindCSS.includeLanguages` settings.

So make sure you configure the below settings as well to allow suggestions inside a string.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
}
```

Comment: I had been having issues with the Tailwind Intellisense for a while now in VS code. The combination I used was a combination of chancruze's answer above AND this answer adding the quickSuggestions to turn strings on (true). Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Add this at the end of your setting.json file in order to get IntelliSense on both HTML and js file

```
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "html": "HTML"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

Add to **settings.json**

You can open via

> cmd + shift + p => Prefences: Open Settings (JSON)

```
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "javascriptreact": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescript",
    "typescriptreact": "typescriptreact",
}
```

Comment: The `typescript` part did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete the "tailwind.config.js" and create it back again with

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

and it should start working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the files, in which you want to work with Tailwind CSS in your **tailwind.config.js** file.
You can replace:

```
content: [],
```

with

```
content: ["*"],
```

It will include all files in your project. Save it and now the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense will popup the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled Tailwind CSS IntelliSense, then reinstalled it back. And the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Both combined worked for me.

```
   "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "html": "HTML"
      },
```

and

Try to delete the "tailwind.config.js" and create it back again with

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Answer (score 0):

Placed the following snippit in VSCode’s settings.json file.

```
"tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true, // remove this line if you don't use Emmet
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
   "strings": true
},
"css.validate": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

The last version of tailwindcss for this time is 3.2.1 and it seems this version is not matched with the last version of vsCode or  IntelliJ IDEA so I downgraded tailwind to 3.1.8 (`npm i tailwindcss@3.1.8`) and then those ways that guys suggest work now

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines of code but it did not work. However, updating my vscode to the latest version did the trick for me.

```
    "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": { "plaintext": "javascript" },
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    },
    "css.validate": false,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I fixed by just creating a file in the root folder in my project named `tailwind.config.js`, then it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you still can not fix this problem:

1. Uninstall Tailwind CSS Intellisense from your VSCode and close it
2. Go to where your vscode exntensions are stored, mine is "C:\Users\Admin.vscode\extensions" (You can open this folder by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P in VSCode, and then search for "Extensions: Open Extensions Folder")
3. Check if there're any folders called **bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss**, if yes then delete all of those
4. Now, re-open your VSCode and install Tailwind CSS Intellisense once again

Comment: how to fix it on macos?

Comment: It's the same on macos, you will have to find the directory leading to where the vscode extensions are stored, on macOS it's ~/.vscode/extensions. You can open that folder by using this shortcut in VSCode: Ctrl + Shift + P. And then search for "Extensions: Open Extensions Folder"

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, my scenario is that I'm using WSL to "store" my projects but my VS code was installed in my windows. What I did was open the WSL prompt, navigate to the project folder and run `code .`. This is what worked for me and I was struggled on that for a few days

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything mentioned above, I simply updated my VS Code, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) extension details page:

> editor.quickSuggestions
>
> By default VS Code will not trigger completions when editing "string" content, for example within JSX attribute values. Updating the editor.quickSuggestions setting may improve your experience:

> `"editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": "on" }`

Answer (score 0):

To me I added;
`content: [ './pages/**/*.{html,js}', './components/**/*.{html,js}', ]`
Inside the content and it started working fine after that, I used vite to create my react aplication

Answer (score 0):

### Some extensions can cause such issues

I ran into the same issue where *Quick Suggestions* stopped working after installing the **[Explorer Exclude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterSchmalfeldt.explorer-exclude)** extension. Disabling the extension resolved the problem, suggesting potential conflicts between Quick Suggestions and **Explorer Exclude**.