# TailwindCSS Intellisense recommending wrong classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, intellisense, vite

i am trying to setup tailwindcss intellisense in my vite react typescript project but it doesn't work correctly, it shows me these classes instead:
[image]

I browsed through stackoverflow for answers and already tried installing HTML CSS Extension and adding code the settings.json. However it didn't work right. It seems that the intellisense is reading a wrong config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense does not provide suggestions in a ReactJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190041/tailwind-css-intellisense-does-not-provide-suggestions-in-a-reactjs-project)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Visual Studio Code, it worked.

Also, i can not explain why, but it helped for me to rename my `tailwind.config.js` to `tailwind.config.cjs`