# Tailwind CSS IntelliSense not working in VSCode, CSS suggestions missing, have tried near everything

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm facing an issue with Tailwind CSS IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). The problem is that I'm not getting any CSS-related suggestions while working with Tailwind CSS. My Tailwind CSS works perfectly fine, and I have the tailwind.config.js file in my project directory, along with Tailwind CSS installed both globally and locally.

The issue is consistent across different projects, whether it's a Next.js or React project. Surprisingly, I receive JS-related suggestions (as seen in the provided image), but no CSS-related ones. [image of my suggestions tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQNQk.png)

I have tried various solutions posted in Stack Overflow and other sources to fix the issue. Here's what I've tried:

Tweaking the settings.json file in VSCode: I added `"strings": true` to ``editor.quickSuggestions```` and

```
"includeLanguages": { "html": "html", "javascript": "javascript", "css": "css" } to "tailwindCSS"
```

in the settings.json file.
Installing relevant extensions: I added `"HTML CSS Support", "CSS Peak,"` and `"IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML"` extensions to my VSCode setup.
Reinstalling IntelliSense and VSCode: I uninstalled and reinstalled the `"Tailwind CSS IntelliSense"` extension and even reinstalled VSCode itself.
Using the ```Ctrl + Space`` shortcut: I tried the suggested keyboard shortcut to trigger IntelliSense suggestions but only got JS-related suggestions.
Screenshot of Output Tab for Tailwind CSS IntelliSense: [output tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSKT1.png)

Below is the content of my settings.json file. Despite trying these steps, Tailwind CSS IntelliSense continues to remain unresponsive.

Any assistance in resolving this long-standing issue would be highly appreciated, as it would significantly boost my productivity as a new front-end developer.

settings.json contents:[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtjIQ.png)

Comment: try these solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190041/tailwind-css-intellisense-does-not-provide-suggestions-in-a-reactjs-project